# How to create user generated pages in asp.net C# from form

Tags: c#

I am new to asp.net C#. How can I create a form where a user can fill out a couple of text fields (page name for instance) and then create a new page on submit. Then they would be able to select the page from a select box and go to it to add content.

I don't know how to implement this and I do not need a full on CMS.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  That said, we're not going to create a full solution for you.  What have you tried?  What issues are you experiencing?

Comment: *"Then they would be able to ... got to it and add content"* imho describes a full blown CMS because it means inline editing instead of putting some values from a form to a (templated) page.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the form to enter the values into a sql table. so, for instance you'd have a title text box, a content text box, and then a button. In your button action you will enter that data to the table. 
then you can create a navigation that for intance - to keep it very simple - does a select all titles from table name. you'll have these titles as your pages. so, upon clicking the title you'd have a script to bring up the details.
This is a very simple overview of how you can create pages.
since you said you are new I'd recommend going through some tutorials. I highly recommend plural sight http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/

hope this helps!